# Flutter - Text Field doesn't scroll up when keyboard appears

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hello i have a issue whereby textfield doesn't scroll up when the keyboard appears.
I also added the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` and also wrapped the tree with SingleChildScrollView but still same issue.

My code :

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            // fit: StackFit.expand,
            overflow: Overflow.visible,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.001 * -5,
                right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1000 * -0,
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.1,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/slide3.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1 / 20),
        Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Create an Account',
                style: GoogleFonts.workSans(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 23,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              Text(
                'Create an account to continue an awesome experience',
                style: GoogleFonts.workSans(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              // SizedBox(
              //   height: 30,
              // ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              InputWidget(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                controller: _usernameController,
                label: 'Username',
                hint: 'johndoe',
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              InputWidget(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                controller: _emailController,
                label: 'Email Address',
                hint: 'johndoe@email.com',
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              InputWidget(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                controller: _passwordController,
                label: 'Password',
                isObscure: true,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
              ),
              Center(
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Get.to(() => BottomBar());
                  },
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: signUpUser,
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: primaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: _isLoading
                            ? Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              )
                            : Text(
                                'Create Account',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Get.to(() => LoginPage());
                },
                child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'Already have an account? ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.workSans(color: Colors.black),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'Login',
                      style: GoogleFonts.workSans(
                        color: primaryColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Result of the code above
[image]

Custom widget included
InputWidget

```
return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
  Text(
    widget.label,
    style: GoogleFonts.workSans(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontSize: widget.fsize ?? 16),
  ),
  SizedBox(height: 3),
  Container(
      height: widget.height ?? 60,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: primaryColor, width: 1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        maxLines: widget.maxLine ?? 1,
        controller: widget.controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: widget.hint,
          hintStyle: GoogleFonts.workSans(
            fontSize: widget.fsize ?? 15,
          ),
        ),
        obscureText: widget.isObscure,
      )),
]);
```

Comment: Please provide `InputWidget`. It seems at it is a custom widget you created. I can't test your code, or improve on it to give you a solution without it and many other dependencies there like Get.to or the controllers for example. Please paste full codes that will help us help you.

Comment: Hi, i just added the inputWidget code

Comment: its not enough, see put the full file codes , I'm seeing widget.hint, widget.fSize, its all throwing errors. but an entire stuff that can permit replicating so we can debug. even the original scaffold file